# How to sum a databound column using knockout or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the folowing table in my view:

```hmtl
 <table border="0" id="tbl">
    <tr class="te">
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>METHOD</th>
        <th>DEPOSIT</th>
        <th>WITHDRAWAL</th>
        <th>MEMO</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: account -->
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: transactionDate"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: tranType"></span> </td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: deposit"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: withdrawal"></span> </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <tr class="last">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>***TOTAL DEPOSIT --- SHOULD GO HERE***</td>
        <td>***TOTAL WITHDRAWAL --- SHOULD GO HERE***</td>
        <td>""</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See below my Account Knockout object:

```
var Account = function (data) {
    this.transactionDate = ko.observable(data.transactionDate);
    this.payorPayee = ko.observable(data.payorPayee);
    this.amount = ko.observable(data.amount);
    this.isDebit = ko.observable(data.isDebit);
    this.tranType = ko.observable(data.tranType);

    this.deposit = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        //some code
    });
    this.withdrawal = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        //some code
    });
}
```

As you can see, I loop through the account object and display the information on a table.

the JSON with the Account info looks like this:

```
[{
    "transactionDate": "1/1/2016",
    "payorPayee": "AAAAA",
    "amount": "111",
    "isDebit": false,
    "tranType": "qqqq"
}, {
    "transactionDate": "1/1/2016",
    "payorPayee": "BBBBB",
    "amount": "222",
    "isDebit": false,
    "tranType": "wwww"
}, {
    "transactionDate": "1/1/2016",
    "payorPayee": "CCCCC",
    "amount": "333",
    "isDebit": false,
    "tranType": "eeee" 
}]
```

What I need to do is loop through the rows, sum the deposit fields and display the total on the Total Deposit field (last 'tr'), then repeat the process for the Withdrawal fields.
I doubt it if it makes more sense to do it using Jquery on page load, or using Knockout.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why is the class that represents a single transaction called `Account`, and not `Transaction`? 2) It seems that you already have written computeds that calculate `deposit` and `withdrawal`. What makes creating two additional computeds called `totalDeposit` and `totalWithdrawal` difficult?

Comment: Thank you. 1)This is not the Transaction info, this is the account info of each transaction so I called it Account. 2) You are right, i understood that it should be similar but for some reason couldn't think of how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like what you did in your `deposit` and `withdrawal` computed, you should also make a computed observable in your viewmodel for the total deposit and total withdrawal. You just need to loop through your `account` array and extract the sum of the deposits and withdrawals.

for example:

```
this.totalDeposit = ko.computed(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    //i don't know if account is observableArray or just plain array
    this.account.forEach(function(account){
        sum += Number(account.deposit());
    });
   return sum;
});
```

And so on and so forth, just create another computed for `totalWithdrawal`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, I understood that it should be similar to what I did with deposit and withdrawal computed but wasn't sure how exactly. It works but it just concatenates the deposit and the withdrawal as strings and not as integers. Foe example- my total deposit looks like this: "111222333", would you be able to help me parsing it to an integer? Thank you!

Comment: I got it. i just changed your code to: sum += Number(account.deposit()); Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Oh no biggie, just remember that javascript is a very popular language, so you just need a little google to find your answers especially those generic stuffs like integer parsing ;)

Comment: This is exactly what i did:) Thanks a lot!